# How to get cursor count without LIMIT?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a `ListView` set up from a cursor that grabs the first 10 rows in a database (LIMIT).

```
    cursor = db.query("MYTABLE",
            new String[]{"_id", "NUMBER", "NAME"}, null, null, null, null, null, "10");
```

The list is set up to "infinitely scroll". It does this by comparing the number of items in the list and the number of items in the database once a scroll completes (`onScroll` from `OnScrollListener`)

```
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
                {
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);

                    long numberOfItemsInDB = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "MYTABLE");
                    long numberOfItemsInList = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
                    long difference = numberOfItemsInDB - numberOfItemsInList;

                    if (difference > 0) {
                    ... //do stuff here 
                    }
```

This works. But sometimes the list may be populated with items from a custom cursor (from search filtering for example) and so I would need the item count of that cursor. I can have a consistent count by using `.getCount()` but if I have already used LIMIT then it will just return the LIMIT I had which was 10.

How can I get the number of items in a cursor ignoring the limit?

Comment: Your code is using the paging method you would normally use with getting data from a remote server.  When you are getting data from the local database, you don't need that paging logic.  The `Cursor` class -- specifically the `SQLiteCursor` class -- handles all the paging internally.  With a `CursorAdapter` and a recycling `ListView`, you have everything you need.  Put in your query for the entire data set you want, get the `Cursor`, and let `CursorAdapter` and `ListView` take care of the rest.

Comment: @krislarson So I should have my cursor pull the entire database and use cursoradapter to limit it? I'm not sure what you mean by paging logic, where is that build in to listview, can it handle automatic scroll loads out of the box?

Comment: By paging I mean the logic you put in your `onScroll` method -- scroll down until a certain point, then go get more items to show. The 10 items would represent a "page".  Now, when you run a query and generate a `Cursor`, the entire query data does not go into memory. If you want, you can look up classes like `CursorWindow` and read the source code to see how cursors work.  Nevertheless, if you query for everything you want in your `ListView` and put the resulting `Cursor` in a `CursorAdapter`, you will be able to scroll through your entire list with no noticeable performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to get Row Count in table.

```
public synchronized long getRowCount(String TABLE_NAME) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);
}
```

To get the Table row count with `where` clause

```
public synchronized long getRowCount(String TABLE_NAME) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME, "NAME like ?", new String[]{"%D%"})
}
```

Comment: This would return the row count of the table. I am after the row count of a cursor without the limit.

Comment: it will return the row count without limit.

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries for more information.

Comment: You misunderstand. I do not want the number of items in my database, I know how to get that count. I want the number of items from my cursor (which won't always be the entire database). My cursor could be all names beginning with D.

Comment: Then you can use `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME, "NAME like ?", new String[]{"%D%"});`

Comment: Please check the utils method of [DatabaseUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) class.

Comment: So you're saying to check the items in a cursor I would have to build a new query and check the items in that query? Is there not a better way? Someone deleted their answer of `select rows found`, is that something?

Comment: This is the best possible answer i know. Wait for some other person to answer your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear at all. If difference is >0 then I do a new query with all the conditions the same but limit now would be 20 (e.g.) instead of 10. And then when scrolls again, it would be 30. So on every scroll, another 10 items are grabbed from the database. To do this, I need the cursor I started with and in the limit argument I would up it. So, is there a way of getting the cursor?

Comment: No `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: @krislarson I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, is there something I can do with that?